# Sessions and how to assign a variable to session array?

Tags: php, session

So basically I know how sessions work, but I'm struggling with setting a variable in `$_SESSION` array. I tried assigning boolean true and $username to a `$_SESSION ["login"]` but in both situations, then I check if the `$_SESSION["login"]` is set, it appears to be empty and redirects to the login page. I checked several existing questions about sessions, but still couldn't find the solution to my problem. Here is the part from login.php where session variable assigns to `$username`

```
<?php
include("db.php");
session_start();
$error = '';
if(!isset($_SESSION["login"])){
    if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
        if (empty($_POST["username"]) or empty($_POST["password"])) {
            $error = "Please enter your login details";
        } else {

            $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST["username"]);
            $password = md5($_POST["password"]);



            $query = mysqli_prepare($conn, "SELECT password FROM workers WHERE user_name=?");
            mysqli_stmt_bind_param($query,"s",$username);
            mysqli_stmt_execute($query);
            mysqli_stmt_bind_result($query,$pass);
            if(mysqli_stmt_fetch($query)){
                if ($password == $pass){
                    $_SESSION["login"] = $_POST["username"];
                    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'welcome.php'; </script>";


                }else {
                    $error = "You typed the wrong password";
                    unset($username, $password);
                }
            }else{
                $error = "User Login doesn't exists";
                unset($username,$password);
            }

        }
    }
}else{

    echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'welcome.php'; </script>";
    exit();
}
?>
```

Here is welcome.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
    if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
        $username = $_SESSION["login"];
    } else {
         echo "<script type='text/javascript'> document.location = 'login.php'; </script>";
         die;
    }
```

How can i solve the problem and why does it happen?

Comment: on your first code `session_start();` is misisng

Comment: Did you put space characters before `<?php` tag in welcome.php? Because that will prevent `session_start` to start a new session

Answer (score 0):

You have to Start Session whenever you want to declare them and not only when you're going to use it. You need to start session on the page that you declare the sessions variables

Comment: I know, just decided to not include the whole .php code, but it's there in both welcome.php and login.php

Comment: I see... I can't find why session is not working. Try put your session_start() before include("db.php"). Put in the first line before your php tag. Dump all session variable, then use die on your welcome.php page right after session_start(): 
` echo '<pre>'; 
var_dump($_SESSION); 
echo '</pre>';
 die; `